# Auto Fitting Content?

Tags: html, resize, autoresize, liquid-layout

I want to know how http://staffanstorp.se/ has the capability of flowing content (I believe thats the term, please correct me if I'm wrong). I will also change the tags in accordance so others may find this post when people have answers because I found it hard to find anything.

Anyway, I have been trauling the web for a possible jquery plugin that will do this for me. The site above is exactly what I need and I am very grateful for help :D

The only things I have been able to find have been done this type of auto resizing for content but only for the text, this site does the lot!

Comment: have a google search for 'responsive design' - that should get you started...

Comment: Cool site.. great question.. I thought first its just jQuery.. but the CSS is pretty funky and the @media stuff in the answers is something i never explored..

Answer (score 1):

It's done by using [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) combined with [liquid css layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G146).

Otherwise instal firebug and start analyzing the code - it's all there on site.

Comment: Perhaps, but it's far more advanced I think. Everything is seemless, and if it is created with multiple jquery scripts, that is some skill on the developers side :D.

Comment: @Giles Wilkinson Ofcourse there is some skill involved - that's why you pay/are paid for coding...

Answer (score 1):

This is done using Media queries within the css file. eg

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
img {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: -512px; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 512px){
img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: -512px; }
}
```

This css provides rules for all images to limit their size to 400px when the screen is 1024px or less wide and limiting them to 200px when the screen is 512px or less wide.

By creating separate rules that work for different screen sizes you can provide this kind of dynamic layout.

The second way is by not defining anything in fixed terms. Using % widths etc will allow your page to fit any size and then you can use the media queries above to move content around when the screen becomes too small.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Will this scale in real time or is it dependant on page rendering?

Comment: @Giles Wilkinson - it will scale in real time - each time you resize the browser it does a check.